# No converter found capable of converting from type [spring boot, spring data, JpaRepository]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

i have two entities  Users and Role

Class Users

```
package com.domain;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String fio;

    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Class Role

```
package com.domain;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Transient
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;
}
```

three tables were automatically created, ok

Then i created repository

```
package com.repository;

import com.domain.Role;
import com.domain.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Set;

@Repository
public interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    Users findByUsername(String Username);
    Set<Role>  findRoleByUsername(String Username);
}
```

and tryed used findRoleByUsername in my controller

Method in my controller

```
    @GetMapping( "/role")
    public Set<Role> roletestpage() {
        Set<Role> myrole = myUserRepository.findRoleByUsername("admin");
        return myrole;
    }
```

when i run my programm i have error

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.domain.Users] to type [com.domain.Role]] with root cause
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.domain.Users] to type [com.domain.Role]
```

my problem is in the findRoleByUsername method.
anybody know, what is this, and how can i solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot use the same repository for multiple entities, you need to fetch the user instead of roles, then introduce a service layer between repository and controller which will serve roles of the user fetched in the repo.

Comment: Berk Kurkcuoglu, thank you )

Answer (score 0):

Repository for the above entities are,

```
@Repository
public interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    Users findByUsername(String Username);
}     
  
@Repository
public interface RolesRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Set<Role>  findByUsers_username(String Username); 
}
```

Using method findByUsers_username(String Username) you will get a set of Roles of a  particular username.
In Controller use,

```
@GetMapping( "/role")
public Set<Role> roletestpage() {
    Set<Role> myrole = myRoleRepository.findByUsers_username("admin");
    return myrole;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User repository-

```
public interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
    Users findByUsername(String Username); }
```

Role repository-

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
        Set<Role> findByUsers_Username(String username); }
```

This will translate to `role.users.userName`

Then add service layers for the two repositories

Role Service

```
 @Service
    public class RoleService {
        @Autowired
        RoleRepository roleRepository;
        public Set<Role> findRoleByUsername(String username) {
            return findByUsers_Username(String username);
        }
```

User Service

```
@Service
        public class UserService {
            @Autowired
            UserRepository userRepository;
     // Add functions 
            }
```

And finally, add the controller.

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {
    @Autowired
    RoleService roleService;

@GetMapping( "/role")
    public Set<Role> roletestpage() {
        Set<Role> myrole = roleService.findRoleByUsername("admin");
        return myrole;
    }
```